# PHP parse error when using dot (.) inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, parse-error

When I run the following code:

```
<?php
private $config = [
  'cacheFile' => 'a'.'b'
];
```

I receive:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in ...
```

My config is:
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14,
Server API  FPM/FastCGI,
nginx/1.4.6

I tested the code above also on localhost(OS X El Capitan) with Nginx/Apache and both tests passed ok.

Any idea where can be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that this is a class property, the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) state that: `declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`... concatenation is a run-time operation

Comment: is that a class property?

Comment: @bub: pretty much would have to be. there's no such thing as a "private" general variable in php. private's only for classes.

Comment: Yes it is. But why two tests on different localhosts passed?

Comment: @MarcB Thank you I know that. Mihi What is your php version? For me it works fine

Comment: Server: PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14, Server API FPM/FastCGI, nginx/1.4.6 Localhost: PHP Version 5.6.12, Server API FPM/FastCGI, Apache/2.2.31 and nginx/1.4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs):

> Status: Implemented in PHP 5.6

> This RFC brings static scalar expressions to the parser. This allows places that only take static values (const declarations, property declarations, function arguments, etc) to also be able to take static expressions.

Therefore your 5.5 cannot do this.

Note that only expressions which can be evaluated at compile time would work, so

```
class foo {
   $x = 'a' . 'b'; // ok - can be calculated at compile-time
   $y = $_POST['foo']; // not ok - only calculable at runtime.
}
```

Comment: I installed php5.6 on server and now it works. Thank you!